# Disabling user capability to edit_posts or delete_posts in the front-end

Tags: users, user-roles, front-end, capabilities

I've created a post edit form in front-end of the site, this form is accessible on the front-end ONLY if the user is logged in. Now, for some reason, upon a certain condition is met, I want to DISABLE user capability to edit or delete the post and keep it read only.

I've modified the above mentioned user's capabilities (using a plugin) and have  confirmed it via `user_can( $user, $capability )` that the user no longer has `edit_posts` and `delete_posts` capability.

Now the issue is, the user is still able to edit or delete post(s) via front-end form or delete link. Is there something I am missing? Do I manually have to hook into some action/filter to stop edit/delete_posts action? If so, how can I do it?

**Note:** All relevant `edit_*_posts` and `delete_*_posts` are also disabled.

Answer (score 1):

By using this functionality we can able to remove the delete option of the page or post.

```
function wp_restrict_page_deletion( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) 
 {
   $post_id = $args[0];
   if ( $cap === 'delete_post' && $post_id === your post id* ) 
     {
       $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';
     }
   return $caps;
 }
 add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', 'wp_restrict_page_deletion', 10, 4 );
```

I think this one is apt for your requirement.

your post id*->Here you need to give the post id of the page or posts,thats you need to remove the delete option.